# How can I switch between a live and a production database without duplicating code?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my situation.  I have an extensive REST based API that connects to a MongoDB database using Mongoose.  The API is written as a standard "MEAN" stack application.

Currently, when a developer queries the API they're always connecting to the live production database.  What I want to do is have an exact duplicate database as a "staging" database, where new data will be added first, vetted over a period of time, and then move to the live database.  Then I want developers to be able to query either one simply by modifying their query.

I started looking into this with the Mongoose documentation, and it appears as though the models are tied to the DB connection, and if I want to have multiple connections I also have to have multiple models, one for each connection.  This would be a nightmare of WET code and not the path I want to take.

What I want to do is not touch any of my code at all and simply have a switch that changes to the proper database for a given query.  So my question is, how can I achieve this? Is it possible? The documentation seems to imply it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to maintain connections two environments in the same code base have you considered setting up stage version of your application? Which database it connects to could be set through an environment variable or some other configuration option.

The developers would still then only have to make a change to query one or the other and you could migrate data from the stage database to production/live database once you have finished your vetting process.

Comment: I did consider it but it really isn't the ideal solution for a couple of reasons.

1. It means added resources to run a new server instance
2. It means dealing with a new subdomain, and a new SSL certificate